# returning a nested object which is in an array using an api in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using an API with a Reactjs project
this is a preview of an object from my API:

```
    {
    "id": "786e8fe8-ab7a-4659-8d89-7ca3d7aafa78",
    "owner": {
        "id": "19b70b73-94a4-4bb7-baf1-73103d793c91",
        "name": "John",
        "email": "John@gmail.com",
        "username": "John",
        "location": null,
        "short_intro": null,
        "bio": "",
        "profile_image": "/images/profiles/user-default.png",
        "social_github": null,
        "social_twitter": null,
        "social_linkedin": null,
        "social_youtube": null,
        "social_website": null,
        "created": "2021-08-12T21:04:41.277498Z",
        "user": 2
    },
    "tags": [
        {
            "id": "e76121ab-2397-4b75-993d-63d236d32530",
            "name": "Django",
            "created": "2021-08-12T23:31:15.681455Z"
        }
    ],
    "reviews": [
        {
            "id": "94e8682e-e73d-4df4-92ab-f9a71195ef90",
            "body": null,
            "value": "up",
            "created": "2021-08-22T07:54:39.070325Z",
            "owner": "19b70b73-94a4-4bb7-baf1-73103d793c91",
            "project": "786e8fe8-ab7a-4659-8d89-7ca3d7aafa78"
        }
    ],
    "title": "zain's 4 project",
    "description": "John project",
    "featured_image": "/images/unicrorn_fee_gwilI9S.PNG",
    "demo_link": null,
    "source_link": null,
    "vote_total": 1,
    "vote_ratio": 100,
    "created": "2021-08-20T05:39:17.087447Z"
}
```

While I'm able to get the `id` and the `owner.name` in my frontend I'm not able to get the `tags` object which is inside an array.
If I try to get the tags by using a `map` function in React I get an error:
`Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, name, created}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Here is my React code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
function Projects() {
    const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/projects/")
            .then((res) => {
                return res.json();
            })
            .then((res) => {
                setProjects(res);
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }, []);
    return (
        <section class="projectsList">
            {projects.map((project) => (
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="grid grid--three">
                        <div class="column">
                            <div class="card project">
                                <a
                                    href=""
                                    class="project"
                                >
                                    <img
                                        class="project__thumbnail"
                                        src=""
                                        alt="project thumbnail"
                                    />
                                    <div class="card__body">
                                        {project.title}
                                        <h3 class="project__title"></h3>
                                        <p>
                                            <a
                                                class="project__author"
                                                href=""
                                            >
                                                By
                                                {project.owner.name}
                                            </a>
                                        </p>
                                        <p class="project--rating">
                                            <span>{project.vote_ratio}%</span>
                                            <br />
                                            Positive Feedback ( Positive
                                            Feedback ({project.vote_total}) Vote
                                            {project.vote_total}
                                        </p>
                                        <div class="project__tags">
                                            {/*---Here is the problem---*/}
                                            {project.tags.map(tag => (

                                                <span class="tag tag--pill tag--main">
                                                <small>{tag}</small>
                                            </span>
                                                ))}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}
        </section>
    );
}

export default Projects;
```

How can I get the tags object which is inside an array?

Comment: You are already getting the object, eg `tag` in the map callback. React is complaining that you are trying to put that object directly in the element. Either build some html from your `tag` object, eg `<div>{tag.name}</div>` or stringify it if you just want to display the whole object for whatever reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `project.tags` property is a collection. This means that the `Array#map` function receives an Object as an argument in the callback function.

You should destructure this Object or use dot notation to get the correct property.

```
{project.tags.map(tag => (
    <span class="tag tag--pill tag--main">
    <small>{tag.name}</small>
  </span>
))}
```

Or

```
{project.tags.map(({ name }) => (
    <span class="tag tag--pill tag--main">
    <small>{name}</small>
  </span>
))}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to output the whole tag object when you do -

```
<small>{tag}</small>
```

You need to access a single (primitive) property on tag instead, e.g. -

```
<small>{tag.name}</small>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mapping the tags, each tag is an object with three properties: id,name,created. you can display each of them with tag.id, tag.name,... . but you cannot pass a whole object to be rendered inside a react element.

```
                                    <div class="project__tags">
                                        {/*---Here is the problem---*/}
                                        {project.tags.map(tag => (

                                            <span class="tag tag--pill tag--main">
                                            <small>{tag.name}</small>
                                            <small>{tag.id}</small>
                                            <small>{tag.created}</small>

                                        </span>
```

Answer (score -1):

by this

```
{project.tags.map(tag => (

     <span class="tag tag--pill tag--main">
     <small>`ID: ${tag.id}, Name: ${tag.name}, Created: ${tag.created}`</small>
     </span>
    ))}
```